# HTML - Auto resize text box using CSS while the form details stays center aligned

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am not sure whether this Q is answered before. please advise if there is a way using CSS, I can achieve to center the Form elements centered and when user tries to resize the page, for me the elements should always get resiged to the page size.

I need to achieve this using CSS, not through JS.

Answer (score 3):

To have form elements horizontally centered, that will get wider as the browser window gets wider, and thinner as the browser window gets thinner, you can do this using CSS. However, you will need to contain it in something to do the horizontally centering.

In my example I have used the form element itself to do the horizontal centering.

http://jsfiddle.net/HZkft/1/

```
form { width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto; }
form textarea, 
form input { width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

based on setek answer you can use  min-width, max-width, and calc

```
<form action="#" method="get">
    <textarea cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
    <input type="text" name="given-name" />
    <input type="text" name="family-name" />
</form>
```

the css

```
form { 
    min-width: 200px;/* set the min width here */
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 400px;/* set the max width here */
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
form textarea, 
form input { 
    width: 100%;
}
```

or

```
form { 
    min-width: 200px;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% -20px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% -20px);
    width: calc(100% -20px);
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
form textarea, 
form input { 
    width: 100%;
}
```

Reading:
 [css3 calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

[CSS max-width Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp)